# Make php file use laravel (outside controller)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Web text editor (ckeditor) inside my app uses a php file (with ajax) for loading images inside a folder. Inside that php file I cannot use Laravel functions (like DB or User), which I would really need.

My question is, is there a way to make a php file inside the project, but outside a controller use Laravel functions? The path to my file is .../public/... and not .../app/..., will that make things difficult?

Comment: you will need to load the framework autoloader at least and then it should work. But why don't you use a laravel controller for your ajax request ?

Comment: Because it is a plugin for ckeditor so I don't use controllers. And how do i do the framework autoloader for that particular php file?

Comment: have a look into the index.php file, there should be a inclusion of the autoloader file. just include it the same way in your new file. But there is no guarantee of success, these functions are not intended to be used like that

Comment: CKEditor plugins usually reside in their ckeditor folder and are picked up normally by the CKEditor architecture itself. If you're using ckeditor as php version (not just linking the JS file) you're placing it in the wrong folder - it should be as a package inside vendor/

Comment: The plugin is in the \public\js\ckeditor\plugins\imgbrowse directory and it works well with ckeditor and yes the ckeditor is js itself, but the plugin uses html, php and js and everything works fine, except that inside that php file I would like to be able to use laravel functions.

Comment: @Crozet When I did that I get TokenMismatchException, I'll check if that's because of ajax.

Comment: The view loads before ajax, how can I get to the token from that view, if the view doesn't have laravel functions? I think this would fix it 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
but I cant access csrf_token(), even when I used <?php echo csrf_token() ?> instead of brackets